# Aggregating data in S3 based on certain key

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have a scenario where logs are constantly being written in S3 bucket in JSON format.Logs are being written line by line i.e for each line a different key is added in the bucket. What I want to do is aggregate all the logs having similar requestId together and store that somewhere. 
Any idea on how to proceed with this.

P.S. I have added aws-lambda to to trigger as soon as something is added to the bucket.

Comment: *for each line a different key is added in the bucket* seems like it is going to get expensive.

Comment: The simple answer is: Don't.
Use cloudwatch logs and then send them to Elasticsearch.

Comment: I dont have an option to not use it